# C#, 列挙型で NullReferenceException はハンドルされませんでした。

Tags: c#

NullReferenceException はハンドルされませんでした。
オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト インスタンスに設定されていません。
とエラーが出ます。

mi1.cs

```
namespace mip
{
    public enum enumMessageType
    {
        mtA, mtB, mtC, ...
    }
後略
```

Form1.cs

```
namespace mipTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            QueueInfo qi = new QueueInfo();
            qi.COmmandInfo.MessageType = enumMessageType.mtA; ←ここでエラーがでます。
            後略
```

解決の手がかりはありますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

デバッグ実行を行い、エラーが発生する行でブレークし、 Null になっているものを探してください。

見た感じ、QueueInfoクラスのCOmmandInfoメンバ変数が初期化されていない可能性が高いです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

おっしゃる通り、CommandInfo が初期化されていないだけでした。
お騒がせいたしました。